# Shinyapp published cant make connect to googlesheets

Tags: shiny, google-sheets-api, shiny-server, shinyapps, web-publishing

I made a Shiny app that takes user data and stores it in a googlesheet file. It works perfectly on my local machine, but I can't get it to work once published on shinyapps.io. I suspect it's a permissions issue, but I'm confused.

i tried to get JSON path from Google cloud console (get API to DRIVE/googlesheets), gs4_auth().... still works locally but not from published version